# Do I need to perform ghusl if I have white fluid discharge without any sexual arousal?

Tags: women, ghusl, evil-thoughts

I m a teen girl and my vagina sometime realease a white fluid I didnt masturabate or anything it simply comes out on its own or sometime when I thinking something bad should I have ghusl every time it comes out without masturabating or bad thinking to pray..  Thats usually 3 to 4times a day

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. Could you specify or give examples of the "bad things" you think about for example is there any relation to sexual arousal to it?

Answer (score 1):

The fluids that a woman discharges – other than urine and menstrual blood –  are: **(1)** maniy (sexual fluid), **(2)** madhy (pre-sexual fluid),  **(3)** wady which is thick, cloudy (turbid) and white fluid that exits after urinating or carrying a heavy object, and **(4)** ritubah (mucus/vaginal discharge) and they are all impure. Maniy (sexual fluid), on the other hand, necessitates a complete ritual bath (ghusl) from major ritual impurity (janabah) and the rest of the discharges (madhy, wady, and rutubah) necessitate mere washing of the private parts, the stained parts on the clothes and ablution (wudhu). When one's situation is one of difficulty, hardship and duress such that it is difficult to keep oneself clean from these impurities, then one is excused when it comes to praying or entering a mosque for example. In such a situation, a woman merely washes herself (the affected areas), washes the stained areas on her clothes or changes them, then she takes ablution (wudu') for the fard prayer, and she does not pay attention during her prayer to anything that might be discharging, because she would fall in the category of a person that suffers from chronic condition of uncontrollable discharge of impure fluids. Also, what should be taken into account here is what exits and comes out in terms of the discharges not what remains inside the private part even if it is the sexual fluid (maniy) of a man or virgin woman according to unanimous scholarly opinion or (the maniy) of a married woman according to the popular and standard opinion. It is important not to give in to evil whisperings and promptings from the shaytan particularly when it comes to taharah (matters of cleanliness). So do not over think or over analyse your situation to the extent it causes your undue hardship and causes you to obsess, making it difficult for you to the practice your deen properly, and Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Okay , so you need to understand that there are several types of fluids that come out of sexual organs in Islamic tradition :

- `Mazy` or `Wady` for pre-seminal fluids in general , which come out as a result of thinking of something sexual or getting aroused (transparent color) ( No ghusl required here )
- `Maney` which is the thick white fluid that comes as a result of sexual activity ( Ghusl required here )

The thing you are describing , sounds definitely like `Mazy\wady` rather than `Maney` which is the sexual fluid , considering you didn't masturbate or engage in sexual intercourse [i.e you didn't touch , or physically stimulate the sexual organ] .

Comment: It's different for boys and girls, what you described is applicable to boys not girls.

Comment: @عادل why is it only for boys? any reference?

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum,
I cannot comment much on the above ( if that applies only for both boys & girls )
My query is If after some cuddling & caresses with your wife without any intention of having any sexual intercourse  clear fluid comes out from men’s private part . Can I consider the fluid as wady / Madhy  & if it is so then will I need to do Ghusl . Or just wash the part and change the clothes and do Wuzu   will be enough to stand for salath.

Jzk .